# svn/tortoise: commit existing file from outside of repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I've recently created an SVN repository, from a set of existing files, and made some minor header changes to the files. Another developer had been making extensive changes to some files, before the repository was created, so his development environment is not currently aware of SVN. That is, the files were not checked out of the repository. Unfortunately I was working with an older set of files.

Ideally, I'd like to merge the two, as my minor changes are just to the header, and there shouldn't be any conflicts, but what's the best way of going about it?

I've tried a test where I overwrote a checked out file with his existing one, but it doesn't seem to detect a difference between the current versioned file and the replaced one. It could be done by checking out, overwriting with his copy, committing, then I could check his out and edit it again, but that's work I'd rather avoid, if at all possible. I'm using TortoiseSVN for all this at the moment.

Comment: Maybe this link can help http://stackoverflow.com/q/4317971/395718

Comment: Thanks for that, I had done a search but not seen that one. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he's the 'lead' develloper on this, and you have a fairly low changeset count, consider this path of least resistance... start over.

Create a new repository and check in his files then add your changes.

Comment: +1: Simply copy your changes somewhere else.  That way you can redo the checkout.  Copy your files back in and commit.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I don't see how I can do it automatically, which is a shame, as it's around 100 files. I suppose I could write a mini program to do it for me (but that's another issue...).